# Shortening of prayers when working in a different city

Tags: salat, travelling

Salam.

I live in Lahore, Pakistan where I have my house and family but I work in Islamabad, which is approximately 400 KM away.
My routine is that I travel to Islamabad every Monday and return to Lahore every Friday in order to spend the weekend with my family. I never intend to stay in Islamabad longer than 4 to 5 days.
My question is, am I allowed to pray shorter prayers (qasr prayers I believe they are called) in Islamabad or in Lahore?

Thank you.

Comment: What you can clearly do is praying qasr on your way if you are sure not to get to your target before the time of a prayer ends. Else the answer can be as different as there are madhabs. Ibadi consider anybody as musafir once he left his home even if it is for studying abroad etc.. Most others would say if you are permanently staying at this location for a couple of more than 4 days (20 fard succesive prayers) you must pray the prayer fully ... and it could be also still be conisdered as traveling by others.

Comment: There is a rather similar question here: [Should I perform travel prayer after moving to a new city while regularly returning to my old city?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/12981/17163)